# How to assert that mine.get returns nonempty result?

Tags: salt-stack

We use the Salt Mine to discover other minions matching certain criteria, in order to build configuration files. However, for various reasons, typically caching at one level or another, or minions not connecting to the master, the result of `mine.get` could be wrong. The most obvious wrong result is an empty result, i.e. no minions matched the `tgt` argument. Is it possible to cause salt to fail to run a state (either `state.highstate` or `state.sls`) if the `mine.get` result is empty?

For example, consider a Jinja-templated configuration file (e.g. for Apache ZooKeeper):

```
# ...
{% set master_nodes = salt['mine.get']('roles:master', 'network.get_hostname', tgt_type='grain').values() | sort -%}
{% for master_node in master_nodes -%}
server.{{ loop.index }}={{ master_node }}:2888:3888
{% endif -%}
```

If the `mine.get` call matches no minions, then `master_nodes` will be an empty list and so no `server` lines will appear in the configuration file. I'd rather have the state fail to run than silently create a useless configuration. Even better would be to match the number of results against a pillar value (e.g., pillar says there are 3 masters, fail if `mine.get` returns more or less than 3 results).